# How do I use NetPlan to configure PPPoE for the etherent interface in Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Tags: server, 18.04, netplan, pppoe

Can anyone help me, please, to set up a pppoe connection on **Ubuntu 18.04 server**? Before, I had Ubuntu 14.04 server, and I was doing it via *pppoeconf* but now it seems that it is not supported anymore. I've found that I have to use netplan but there is no information how to set the pppoe connection there. In the net, people are showing only the examples for their wired connections, whereas I have no router but just a cable comming to my machine with its login and pswd.

Comment: why do you say "it seems that it is not supported anymore"?

Comment: Because I cannot call it from terminal.. it says "Command not found".

Answer (score 1):

pppoeconf is still the supported method of configuring a PPPOE connection on Ubuntu 18.04.  netplan does not currently have built-in support for pppoe.

The pppoeconf package is installed by default on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop systems; for server systems it is shipped in the apt archive included on the classic ISO so that it is available for selection at install time (or after install time) for users with advanced networking requirements.  It is not currently (up to and including Ubuntu 18.04.3) available on the newer server live image, so users who use this image to install and need pppoeconf for their network will need to acquire the pppoeconf deb out of band and install it.

Comment: But when I call pppoeconf, it says "Command not found".. should I install some package first?..

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end, I used a router first to make a temporary local connection with netplan, and then installed *pppoeconf* package with **apt-get install**. It's strange that it wasn't installed before.. Thanks for your attempts!